# How to control states of sales orders in Odoo SA

Tags: odoo, saas, odoo-9

I want to create a new state for a sales order that is beyond a quotation, but not quite confirmed. I'd also like to have orders that come in from the web portal to go into that state. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have an intermediary step where an inside sales manager can check that all requirements for the customer are taken care of before the order is confirmed and goes to fulfillment. This allows us to have a rep reach out to the customer in the case we need something additional from them.

I'm using Odoo 9 SA so I don't have the ability to build out a module.. so my question really is how can I accomplish this using server actions and the other internal tools? Any suggestions?